# How to get the print the result for python multiprocessing in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, multiprocess

Here is my issue: I am at this point in a class that we are going over multiple processes in Python using jupyter notebook.  I have everything typed the same as the instructor has it. I installed the package as well.  However, I get a solution of {} instead of what she is showing on her screen.

Okay so, the instructor suggested that we install the multiprocess package.
We do this from the command prompt: pip install multiprocess

Here are my results (since I already installed it last week):
C:\Users\sevan\OneDrive\Documents\PythonEssentialTraining\Exercise Files\exercise_files>pip install multiprocess
Requirement already satisfied: multiprocess in c:\users\sevan\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (0.70.15)
Requirement already satisfied: dill>=0.3.7 in c:\users\sevan\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from multiprocess) (0.3.7)

NO big surprise, everything looks like it was successful from what I can understand (I am new to command lines and Python, 3 weeks old here and just in a beginners class).

Now, she tells us to import the process library and the time library into jupyter (I call it a library as that is what R called it back  in the day):

```
from multiprocess import Process
import time
```

Then I typed in the following according to her screen:

```
def longSquare(num, results):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(num**2)

results = {}
p1 = Process(target=longSquare, args=(1,results))
p2 = Process(target=longSquare, args=(2,results))

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()

print(results)
```

When I type CTRL+Enter, I get

{}

What her screen is showing is

```
14
{}
```

I do not know what I have done wrong?

Now, this is an example of a multiprocess, it is not a perfect one. She explains that the 14 should not look like that later in the lesson.  What I need is for jupyter notebook to print out the 14 and {}.  Any suggestions?

This is probably super easy.  Also, I have shut down all other processes in the notebook, any other notebooks, maybe something else is going on in the background?  Also, I get no errors and it does not seem to be hanging as when I add 1+1 at the end, it gives me 2, as that's my test to see if something is hanging.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you restart the kernel after running the install? I'm seeing `1` on the first line of output, `4` on the second line, and the empty set brackets below that. You can see the same thing in a temporary, anonymous Jupyter session by going [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements#python-environment-with-a-requirementstxt), pressing '`launch binder`'. When the session starts up, open a new notebook and first run in a cell `%pip install multiprocess`. Then restart the kernel. (You can delete the install cell now.) Then add your code blocks from here as two cells and run it.

Comment: As to the cause.... there is an **open** report for Python 3.11 and multiprocess on WIndows being an issue [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/97641); however, it doesn't seem exactly similar to what you experience. So it may not be the actual cause here. However, this exact issue is tangential to your learning experience. It should work where I pointed you, and that is probably sufficient for now. Don't get hung up on something you won't need most of the time. And where I pointed you should give you some place to test and compare to your experiences on your own machine.

Comment: Thank you @Wayne This worked. I did not know to restart the kernel. That makes sense though. Also, I did not know how to use GitHub before and was able to load up binder just fine from it. I think I was using jupyter notebook and not jupyter lab. So that also could have been the issue. Though this one did make it so that the 14 was on separate lines: a 1 on the first line, 4 on the second and {} on the third.  That was a little different from her answer, but at least I can say I now know how to restart kernels. lol. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a clarification: MyBinder is loading separate from GitHub. MyBinder just uses GitHub as a source of information about the environment and content for the session. GitHub allows you to share things and so it is useful to share the URLs that MyBinder will use along with the settings for the environment and content. MyBinder is not associated with GitHub. Other repositories even works as you can see if you go to http://mybinder.org and toggle the upper left drop-down menu on the main form. ... Also, I don't think the classic vs. JupyterLab was the issue. ... The 1 or four on separate or ...

Comment: <continued> same lines also may be due to changes in Python or `print()` function or handling by Jupyter between versions your instructor used and you use now.